# Do SharePoint 2010 and Reporting Services 2008 R2 (Integrated Mode) work together via SSL?

Tags: 2010, reporting-services, ssl

We want to use SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services (Integrated Mode) and SharePoint 2010 in a SharePoint Farm with SSL enabled. Especially we'd like to generate reports from SharePoint lists. Is SSL supported in this scenario? Are there any problems we can run into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We now have set up an enviroment with SSL and Reporting Services. Everything works fine.